Parcel cannot find @babel-core, but it is present in node_modules, package.json
The error I receive is as follows:
@parcel/package-manager: Could not find module "@babel/core", but it was listed in package.json. Run your package manager first.
I installed via:
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env

The contents of package.json looks correct:
   "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
        "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.13.0",
        "@parcel/transformer-inline-string": "^2.8.3",
        "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.13.0",
        "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
        "parcel": "^2.13.2",
        "svgo": "^3.0.2",
        "typescript": "^5.7.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@swc/helpers": "^0.5.15",
        "custom-card-helpers": "^1.8.0",
        "home-assistant-js-websocket": "^8.0.0",
        "lit": "^2.7.0"
    }

npm install works fine, and does install node_modules/@babel
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... Thank you for help!
npm run build should just work. This error has been posted before, and the solutions say recent versions of babel fix this, but I still get the error.
